# Creating userform with choosing the range

Tags: excel, function, userform

I am a student and have a task that can not solve for a long time.

So, I need to create userform that will calculate the function y=15*x^3+7*x^2+47*x values for all x in given range. User will choose the range.

Your kind assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why you need UserForm? You can do it by clicking a button, which will run a `sub`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following sub.

```
Sub CalcFunc()
Dim YourRange As Range
Dim EveryCell, x, y

    Set YourRange = Application.InputBox("Select your range.", Type:=8)
    For Each EveryCell In YourRange
        x = EveryCell.Value
        y = 15 * (x ^ 3) + 7 * (x ^ 2) + 47 * x
        MsgBox y
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `MsgBox y` line with your desired output cell/field.

Comment: but, is it possible doing it in userform?

Comment: Yes. Just create a user form. Take a `command button` and write those codes in `command button` click event. Show result in a text box of user form. I don't know what is your skill in `vba`.

Comment: The last question, what will be the command which will show the result in command button. Let's say I have a textbox lbresult ?

Comment: Command `Me.lbresult =y` or `UserForm1.lbresult =y` where UserForm1 is `name` of your form.

Answer (score 0):

yes ofcourse it is possible implementing sub in userform why dont you google **how to add userforms in excel**.. refer the home and learn link below add a button to your user form double click it *(while you are still in the designing mode) place the related code there its easy no rocket science feel free to ask if you have any issues

here are some links visit Home And Learn this is in detail
http://www.homeandlearn.org/getting_started_with_user_forms.html

Still no help?  then visit 
http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html Thanks